# going parallel through two lists in a jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am currently writing a small torrent client with flask.

My problem is that when I deal with files priorities, I have two list of the files to deal with, each one containing specific details/commands about the different files.

And I need to go through both of them in the template at the same time and in parallel (so that each time, we speak about the same file !)

Here is the forms :

```
# each individual file in the torrent have its own priority, thus, we need to manage   them individually !
class TorrentFileDetails(Form):
filename = HiddenField('filename')
priority = SelectField(u'File priority',choices=[('off','off'),('low','low'),('normal','normal'),('high','high')])

class TorrentForm(Form):
hidden      = HiddenField('hidden')
ratiolimit  = DecimalField("ratio")
downloadlimit   = DecimalField("down")
uploadlimit     = DecimalField("up")
bandwidthpriority = SelectField(u'Torrent priority', choices=[( -1,'low'),(0,'normal'),(1,'high')])

# we append each individual file form to this, as we don't know how many there is in each torrent !
files       = FieldList(FormField(TorrentFileDetails))
```

And here is the view part :

```
# fetch informations about the torrent using the transmissionrpc python library
torrent = client.get_torrent(tor_id)

###
    if torrent.seedRatioMode == 0:
        torrent.seedRatioMode = 'Global ratio limit'
    if torrent.seedRatioMode == 1:
        torrent.seedRatioMode = 'Individual ratio limit'
    if torrent.seedRatioMode == 2:
        torrent.seedRatioMode = 'Unlimited seeding'

    control = TorrentForm()
    ###
    files = list()
    for f in torrent.files():
        fx = dict()
        fx['name'] = torrent.files()[f]['name']
        if torrent.files()[f]['selected'] == True:
            fx['priority'] = torrent.files()[f]['priority']
        else:
            fx['priority'] = 0
        fx['size'] = torrent.files()[f]['size']
        fx['completed'] = torrent.files()[f]['completed']
        files.append(fx)
        f_form = TorrentFileDetails(filename=fx['name'],priority=fx['priority'])
        control.files.append_entry(f_form)

    if control.validate_on_submit():
        type(button.data)
        #start_stop_torrent(tor_id)
    return render_template("torrent.html", title = torrent.name, files = files, user = user, torrent = torrent, control = control)
```

Here is the template part :

```
<h2>Files</h2>
<table class="uk-table">
    <tr>
        <th>File name</th>
        <th>Completed / Size</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
    </tr>

    {% for file in control.files %}
    <tr>
        {{file.hidden_tag()}}
        <td>{{file.name}}</td> <- should come from torrent.files() list !
        <td>{{file.completed|filesize}} / {{file.size|filesize}}</td> <- should come from torrent.files() list !
        <td>{{file.priority}}</td>
        {# <td><button type="submit">Send</button></td> #}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

As you can see, I have one list which is those coming from transmission and containing just names, size, basic things. These are not to control and so, not in the form. The other list is the form itself, which contains controls, but can't just show file size or other.

So in the template, I should follow both list accordingly, but don't know how !

Anyone has an idea ? Suggestion ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using HiddenField in the forms to pass the pieces of text I need.

For exemple, filename and size become hiddenfield :

```
filename = HiddenField('filename')
size     = HiddenField('size')
```

After that, I don't need anymore the fx dict, nor the files() list.
In the template, the pieces of text are printed with their value :

```
<h2>Files</h2>
<table class="uk-table">
    <tr>
        <th>File name</th>
        <th>Completed / Size</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
    </tr>

    {% for file in control.files %}
    <tr>
        {# {{file.hidden_tag()}} #}
        <td>{{file.filename.data}}</td>
        <td>{{file.completed.data}} / {{file.size.data}}</td>
        <td>{{file.priority}}</td>
        {# <td><button type="submit">Send</button></td> #}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```